# Timber::render feed.rss.twig with XML content-type header

Tags: php, twig, rss, content-type, timber

I have a custom Wordpress XML RSS Feed that is compiled from a `my-feed.rss.twig` Twig template.

Is there a way to set a `Content-type: text/xml` header in `Timber::render`?

At the moment the following *works* but seems hacky:

```php
// Seems hacky, but works...

Timber::render('my-feed.rss.twig', $context);

header('Content-Type: ' . feed_content_type('rss-http'), true);
```

Comment: According to the documentation for that code, `render()` "Passes data to a Twig file and echoes the output." so your code as shown does not work. If you check your PHP logs you will see 'headers already sent' notice. Call `header('Content-Type: application/rss+xml`);` before you call `Timber::render()`.

Comment: @miken32 Yes, the header should probably go _before_ `Timber::render` but my example _does work_. No notices and the proper content-type header. Again: I did move the `header()` before `Timer::render` but the outcome is exactly the same for me. My Q was if there is not a better way than using `header()`...

Comment: Then their documentation must be wrong, there is absolutely no way to set an HTTP header after content has been output. I think `header()` is the only appropriate function to use to set an HTTP header.